# get data from array in class php

Tags: php, class

I have this code

```
class rfs_payeer
{
    private $url = 'https://payeer.com/ajax/api/api.php';
    private $agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
    private $auth = array();
    private $output;
    private $errors;

    /*======================================================================*\
    Function:   __construct
    Descriiption: Выполняется при создании экземпляра класса
    \*======================================================================*/
    public function __construct($account, $apiId, $apiPass)
    {
        $arr = array(
            'account' => $account,
            'apiId' => $apiId,
            'apiPass' => $apiPass,
        );
            $this->auth = $arr;
    }
    public function isAuth()
    {
        if (!empty($this->auth)){ return true;
        }
        else{
            return $this->auth['account'];
        }
    }
}
```

How to get `$arr['account']` from `isAuth()`?

Comment: If you want to access the array within the function `func()` I'd recommend you just use `$rame`.

Comment: really I have large code,array is in other function and I can't get $rame direct,only using $this->rame

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is more like this...

```
class rame
{
    private $arr=Array();
    public function func()
    {
        $this->arr =array(
            "pir"=>"pirveli",
            "me"=>"meore",
            "mes"=>"mesame"
        );
        echo $this->arr['pir'];
    }
}

$r = new rame();
$r->func();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing it correctly, but your `if` condition is wrong. You are checking whether the array is *not* empty, so you will not get into the `else` part. Remove the `!` operator:

```
if (empty($this->auth)) { 
    return true;
} else {
    return $this->auth['account'];
}
```

See it run with output on [eval.in](https://eval.in/953796)

Or, using the ternary operator:

```
return empty($this->auth) ? true : $this->auth['account'];
```

NB: Are you sure you want to return `true` when the array is empty? It would seem more reasonable to return an empty string, `false` or `null`.

To actually see the result, you must:

1. Assign to `$this->auth` (not to `$auth` like in your other example in comments)
2. Create an instance of the class
3. Call the method `isAuth`
4. Output the returned value

Comment: No.
I tried remove if condition and only 
return $this->auth['account'];
but nothing outpuy

Comment: You must be calling it in a wrong way then, because I put the code as in your question [here](https://eval.in/953796), applied the correction, added a call, and it outputs the data. Also, you are not *outputting* anything in that function, only *returning*. Please check the [fiddle](https://eval.in/953796) how to get the *output*.

Comment: Why would you expect that to output anything? (1) You don't assign anything to `$this-arr` in the method, (2) you never instantiate the class, (3), you never call `isAuth` and (4) you never print the results? Here is the correction: https://eval.in/953808